# How to use date_date_callbacks

Tags: 8, javascript, datetime

In Datetime.php from Core\Datetime\Element, I read:

```
#date_date_callbacks: Array of optional callbacks for the date element.
    Can be used to add a jQuery datepicker.
```

What does it mean? How am I supposed to add a jQuery datepicker from a PHP function? Right now I am doing from a JS file included as a library, but I'd like to keep my custom widget more self contained (I am developing a custom widget to select weeks using jQuery datepicker).

Answer (score 1):

The first argument those callbacks get is `$element` which, essentially, is a render array as described in [Render API overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.8.x). This means, for example, that a #date_date_callbacks callback could use code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_date_callback($element, $form_state, $date) {
  $element['date']['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mylibrary';
  // Optionally, the callback can pass values to the JavaScript code.
  $element['date']['#attached']['drupalSettings']['foo'] = 'bar';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking the official documentation of [DateTime class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21Element%21Datetime.php/class/Datetime/8.0.x), it appears that it calls all the function names passed as string in the `#date_date_callback` array (check `processDatetime` function).

```php
// Allows custom callbacks to alter the element.
if (!empty($element['#date_date_callbacks'])) {
  foreach ($element['#date_date_callbacks'] as $callback) {
    if (function_exists($callback)) {
      $callback($element, $form_state, $date);
    }
  }
}
```

The callback function accepts three arguments `$element` (the main element array), `$form_state` (the current form state) and `$date` (the Date object).
So, a typical situation you would implement `hook_form_alter()` in your module and add your custom callback there.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, &form_state, $form_id) {
  ..
  $form['field_name']['...']['value']['#date_date_callbacks'][] = 'custom_module_date_date_custom_callback';
  ..
}

/**
 * Implements custom date_date callback function.
 */
function custom_module_date_date_custom_callback(&$element, &form_state, $date) {
  ..
  // Do whatever changes you want to do with $element or $form_state.
  ..
}
```

Keep in mind that the `$element` and the `$form_state` are passed by reference here. This is a very important step which ensures that whatever changes you do inside the callback are permanent and are passed to the final rendering of the form element.